# How to enhance iOS Core Data save operation performance

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I have a simple table which has an attribute named "details", of type Transformable.

Now this attribute needs to be updated almost every 3 or 4 seconds as there is some monitoring code which is updated after the given time. Basically a NSDictioanry object is updated every time from different points in the app and it is updated in Core Data as a transformable property.

I have users reporting of phone being heated, since I implemented this thing. Before I was using NSUserDefaults as the data was not that big but due to some structural changes I had to put it in core data. I checked the CPU time profiler and could not find any recursive calls to any other method.

So core data fetch and save operation is going on after every 3 to 4 seconds.

The only thing I can think of is to put the save operation in the applicationWillTerminate of AppDelegate.

But I wonder if there is a way to do it differently. As some articles suggest that application will terminate might not get called sometimes. IS there a way to decrease the overhead of Fetch and save operation?

```
NSArray *results = [[[APPDEL managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:[Info fetchRequest] error:&error] mutableCopy];
    Info *userInfo = [results firstObject];
    if (userInfo.userCredentials)
    {
        userInfo.userDetails = (NSDictionary *)_globalAppCurrentStateDict;
        //[[APPDELEGATE managedObjectContext] save:nil];
    }
```

Shifted the save to willTerminate for now. Will check the performance.

Comment: Saving a single property change every 3-4 seconds doesn't sound like a massive amount of work for Core Data. It's pretty efficient on those kinds of things (assuming you're using a SQLite backend and not XML). I'd start by running your code through instruments, and see where your performance problem really is (try the core data instrument and energy log and file activity, etc. rather than just the CPU instrument). I suspect you're doing something much more intensive than you think you are.

Comment: what if that property is quite big, I mean the dictionary has approx 200 keys

Comment: That sounds like an incorrect use of a dictionary. Yes, that could be painful since it's fighting core data. I would reconsider the model and break this object up.